# Lotus Xpages TypeAhead option changes the DOM id of the label

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages, lotus, type-ahead

[lotus](/questions/tagged/lotus) changes the generated id of a label for an input text field, if the [type-ahead](/questions/tagged/type-ahead) field is enabled for that field.

1. The source on the [xpage](/questions/tagged/xpage) without [type-ahead](/questions/tagged/type-ahead):

`<xp:tr>
            <th scope="row">

                <xp:label id="labelClientRapporteur"
                    for="clientRapporteur">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:clientData['clientRapporteur']}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:label>
            </th>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="clientRapporteur"
                    value="#{complaintDocument.clientRapporteur}">

                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>`

2. And the source of the page in the browser:

`<tr>
<th scope="row">
<label id="view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:labelClientRapporteur" class="xspTextLabel" for="view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:clientRapporteur">Ügyfélreferens</label>
</th>
<td>
<input id="view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:clientRapporteur" class="xspInputFieldEditBox" type="text" name="view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:clientRapporteur">
</td>
</tr>`

3. The code of the [xpage](/questions/tagged/xpage) in case of [type-ahead](/questions/tagged/type-ahead) enabled for the same input:

`<xp:tr>
            <th scope="row">

                <xp:label id="labelClientRapporteur"
                    for="clientRapporteur">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:clientData['clientRapporteur']}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:label>
            </th>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="clientRapporteur"
                    value="#{complaintDocument.clientRapporteur}">
                     <xp:typeAhead mode="partial" minChars="1"
                        ignoreCase="true"
                        valueList="#{javascript:return namesTypeAhead();}" var="lupkey"
                        valueMarkup="true">
                     </xp:typeAhead>
                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>`

4. And the source of the page with [type-ahead](/questions/tagged/type-ahead) field in the browser:

`<tr>
<th scope="row">
<label id="view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:clientRapporteur_label" class="xspTextLabel" for="view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:clientRapporteur">Ügyfélreferens</label>
</th>
<td>
<span id="view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:_id78" mode="partial" jsid="view__id1__id2__id31__id45__id78" dojotype="ibm.xsp.widget.layout.data.TypeAheadReadStore"></span>
<div id="widget_view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:clientRapporteur" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInlineTable dijitLeft xspInputFieldEditBox dijitTextBox dijitComboBox" role="combobox" widgetid="view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:clientRapporteur" aria-labelledby="view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:clientRapporteur_label">
</td>
</tr>`

5. The generated id for the label is:

`view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:clientRapporteur_label`

, instead of the

`view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:clientRapporteur`

. The problem is, that I use

`setTextLabelForRequired("#{id:labelClientRapporteur}");`

to change the style of the label, and this code does not work in this case, because of the changed id of the label.

I would like to know how to fix this id-changing, or what is the best work-around?

Comment: So using setTextLabelForRequired("#{id:labelClientRapporteur}"); on a label with type-ahead fails to return the correct generated id?

Comment: Yes, because the id "view:_id1:_id2:_id31:_id45:clientRapporteur" does not exist in case of the field with type ahead.

Comment: I understand that the generated id changes. But #{id:labelClientRapporteur} should take care of that and return the correct id. Does it return the wrong id?

Comment: im guessing you would need to render your javascript through the lotus engine like with the xpage contents. At least thats what i get from the above comments

Comment: I made a small test (with 8.5.3FP2) and in my test the label does not get "_label" appended to its id if the inputText control has type-ahead enabled. What version of Notes and Domino are you using?

Comment: we use 8.5.3 FP1. The label for property of the label is selected to the inputtext, otherwise the label id does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a feasible workaround as i see it. The optimal would be to have the unique jsid ofc.

This will

1. loop all nodes with selector
2. loop all textboxes
3. lookup registered widget via domNode (not sure how logic is but via Id is definately better)

So:

```
var arr = dojo.filter(dojo.query('.xspInputFieldEditBox'), function(domNode) {

   if(/labelClientRapporteur/.test(domNodes.className))
      return true;

});
var widget = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(arr[0]);
```

Or a little more loosely matched:

```
var nodes = dojo.query('.xspInputFieldEditBox[id*="labelClientRaporteur"]');
var domNode = nodes[0];
```

Comment: The suggested workaround seems working. I replace the xspInputFieldEditBox to xspTextLabel, because we want to find the id of the label, not the input.Thank you for the help.